# Docker Compose remove containers started using docker run

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have two different web projects using that use the same set of docker images to create the API responses. A developer can clone either of these web projects from GitHub and run npm scripts to start the web tier on their local development machine.

**Repo 1**
In this repo the build script for the web tier uses a script file to spin up the containers for the app tier (say the container name is APP_CONTAINER). The port for the app tier is 9090 (for instance) and the web tier runs on 8080. The docker scripts in this repo, checks for any running app (API) container, removes them, pulls the latest image from our internal docker hub and then starts those containers again.

**Repo 2**
In this repo the build script for the web tier uses docker compose to pull and up's the app (API) containers (same name as APP_CONTAINER). The ports for these container needs to be the same 9090 port. The web layer for this repo runs on a different port i.e. port 3000.

My question is, when I run the docker compose in Repo 2, is there a way to remove the container APP_CONTAINER if it is was already created and run by the first repo using a docker run command?

Answer (score 0):

If the container name is always the same (or something you can determine) you could use something like this in bash (or integrate it wherever you call your scripts).

If you just want to stop the already running container:

```
docker stop $(docker ps -q -f name=APP_CONTAINER)
```

If you want to stop and remove the already running container

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -q -f name=APP_CONTAINER))
```

While if you want to remove the existing app container even if this is not running you can use:

```
docker rm $(docker stop $(docker ps -qa -f name=APP_CONTAINER))
```

In the case you have to run this command before `docker-compose up` you can create a script that you run instead of manually starting the containers. Something on the lines of:

```
#!/bin/bash

APP_CONTAINER="APP_CONTAINER" 
docker stop $(docker ps -q -f name=$APP_CONTAINER) 
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: These are the steps I usually take if I were to write up a script. I want these to happen when the developer runs docker-compose up. Can I do them somehow using my docker compose yml configuration?

Comment: What I usually do is add a script in the root that runs all the required operations for the developers (in some case you have to import a database or do some other operation for example).

Updated in the answer otherwise is not readable.